# wireframe modifier +file size

Tags: wireframe

I am trying to add wireframe modifier to a 119 MB 3D scan model on blender. The modifier gets added however does not get rendered. Is this because the model is too big?

Answer (score 0):

If the camera icon is not checked here:

[image]

then the wireframe modifier won't be rendered.

**** UPDATE ****

1. add decimate modifier

[image]

enter 0.01 as value

apply the modifier

then add your wireframe modifier again and try to render.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but the camera icon is checked...

Comment: ok, then please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: I am new to this platform. How would you like me to send you the file I do not see an attach option.

Comment: Normally you would use https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions. But it has limited space. If your file is bigger you could e.g. copy a link to Dropbox or other cloud services.

Comment: Here you go... https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13mJ4mUA0OGNzAwESCqUqCuOk0XuzSgC2?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you. May i ask why you think that you need a model with 5 mio vertices? and r u a beginner in blender?

Comment: in your uploaded file...there is no wireframe modifier at all?

Comment: Hi @chris yes I am a beginner in Blender and don't know much about vertices. Yes I removed it but if you add it it will do the same not render.

Comment: @ShonaliShetty: ok, i am pretty sure you don't need that much vertices. So you should use a decimate modifier first (because with that much vertices you won't see the effect at all). Then try again with wireframe modifier. -> i updated my answer

Comment: thank you! I need to print my work as in not 3D print but paper printing does having a low poly count as suggested above reduce the resolution of the image?

Comment: Yes it will reduce it, but it depends on the size of your print (number of pixels on x and y). Just a little example: if you have 10 pixels on x and 10 on y. So you have 100 pixels in total. So a model with more than 100 pixels wouldn’t improve the image/result, right? So a rendered image with 1000*2000 has 2 mio pixels (and assuming the model just covers around 50% of an image) so a model with 1 Mio Pixel would be more than accurate (because there doesn’t have to be a vertex on each point so that it looks realistic)

Comment: Alright! Thank you. I will try it out.